# How do you build a jsonpath query referencing a column in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jsonpath

This works fine:

```
jsonb_path_query(p.blah::jsonb, '$[*] ? (@.fruit == "banana") ')
```

but if I want to compare the JSON "fruit" property to a value from a column, I cannot get Postgres to parse it, like so:

```
jsonb_path_query(p.blah::jsonb, '$[*] ? (@.fruit == c.fruit) ')
```

I get hard-to-understand errors like "syntax error, unexpected IDENT_P at end of jsonpath input"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All JSONpath functions also accept an additional JSON parameter that contains key/value pairs that can be referenced inside the JSON path expression:

```
jsonb_path_query(jsonb_column, 
                 '$[*] ? (@.fruit == $fp)', 
                 jsonb_build_object('fp', c.fruit) )
```

Comment: Not all, `jsonb_set()` and `jsonb_insert()` being examples.

Comment: @TilmanVogel: those aren't [JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH) functions (they accept a "path", but it's not a "JSONpath" value)

Answer (score 1):

Use `format()` to build the second parameter, e.g.:

```sql
with my_table (fruit, json_col) as (
values
    ('banana', '[{"fruit": "banana"}, {"fruit": "apple"}]'::jsonb),
    ('apple', '[{"fruit": "pear"}]'),
    ('plum', '[{"fruit": "pear"}, {"fruit": "plum"}]')
)

select 
    fruit, 
    jsonb_path_query(json_col, format('$[*] ? (@.fruit == "%s")', fruit)::jsonpath) 
from my_table;

 fruit  |  jsonb_path_query
--------+---------------------
 banana | {"fruit": "banana"}
 plum   | {"fruit": "plum"}
(2 rows)
```