# How to listen to database changes with condition flutter supabase?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, real-time, supabase

How to listen to database changes with condition if the item in a json row in the supabase database?

```dart
supabase.from('countries')
  .stream(primaryKey: ['id'])
  .eq('user_ids', '???') //what code should I replace this line with
  .listen((List<Map<String, dynamic>> data) {
});
```

`user_id` column is a map in `countries` table, for example:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jeo",
  "is_number": false
}
```

I need to request only if the `id = 3` in the `user_id`'s map, what code should I replace to do that?

```dart
eq('user_id', '???')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in your case the column `user_id` has JSON as data type and at top level the JSON objects have a key named `id`. And you want to select based on the JSON key `id`. Then try:

`eq('user_id ->> id', '3')`

It should be possible to use `columnA -> key1`  resp. `columnA ->> key1` syntax for selecting the JSON keys (works also for select). `->` will return a JSON object, `->>` gives you a string.

See:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-json/

Comment: thank you very much thats works, is there any way to check if the map is contains specific value to select it ,for example if many keys in the map has int value how to check if any value of them is 3 without specify the key?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it's possible. The postgres documentation for JSON is quite complex see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73978560/how-do-you-build-a-jsonpath-query-referencing-a-column-in-postgres